# "Ci sono stato" vs "sono stato lì/là"

Tags: difference, pronouns, adverbs, particles

In a hypothetical dialogue between two friends:

> –  I love that theater. 
>    –  I have been there yesterday.

It seems to me that I can translate the second sentence to "ci sono stato ieri" or "sono stato lì/là ieri". Is there any difference between both?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only difference is a difference of emphasis. It's not uncommon in Italian (and in other Romance languages) to have two sets of pronouns, one clitic and unable to carry the stress and one not clitic.

For example see *Mi ha chiamato* and *Ha chiamato me*, where the only difference is that in the second sentence there is more emphasis put on the fact that *I* was the person called. The same pattern can be found here, where *ci* is a clitic variant of *lì* and *là* (and in fact it can also have the meaning of *qui*).

Normally (and especially in the spoken language) one does not feel the need for the added emphasis that the non-clitic particles provide, so clitics are used.

Comment: Thanks! It seems to me that the construction with "ci" is much more usual? If so, it'd be nice to add that information to the answer.

Comment: @AlanEvangelista Usual is in the eye of the  beholder. Usually there's no need the added emphasis that the *lì,là* construction provides and so the clitic are preferred. I'll add a paragraph on this to the answer anyway.